# Regex to Match "Chinese+Number" pattern in Python

Tags: python, regex

In Python 3.3, I want to match the pattern below, but it keeps failing.

```
摄氏零下253
```

I used the regex below.

```
[^\x00-\x47\x58-\x7F]+
```

Dosen't it exclude all of ascii except digits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up the decimal and hexadecimal values for ASCII numbers. The `\x` escape sequence denotes a hexadecimal escape, for which you should use the hex value of the ASCII character you need.

Referring to the ASCII table (http://www.asciitable.com/), the range should be `0` to `2F` and then `3A` to `7F`, and your regex should look like this:

```
[^\x00-\x2F\x3A-\x7F]+
```

However, the above regex does include characters besides Chinese ones (in fact, it includes everything except the 127 ASCII characters minus the digits).

Comment: That's true, but I wanted to point it out to the OP in case it leads to errors in the future.

Answer (score 9):

Depending on what programming language you are using, you could use the following.

```
[\p{Han}\p{N}]+
```

> `\p{Han}` matches characters in the Han script.
>   `\p{N}`   matches any kind of numeric character in any script.

[**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/xG0oF5/2)

Comment: `\p{N}` doesn't work in Java, any idea what the equivalent is?

Answer (score 1):

Unsure what language you would be doing this in, but this regex works in PHP when [using predefined Unicode scripts](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category):

```
/(?:[\p{Han}0-9]+)/simu
```

Ditto with this which might be more portable since not all implementations of regex have the predefined Unicode scripts set:

```
/[\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}0-9]+/simu
```

And here is some test code with both regex in place; comment one or the other out to test:

```
// Set the test string.
$string = '摄氏零下253';

// Run it through preg_match.
// $regex = "/(?:[\p{Han}0-9]+)/simu";
$regex = "/[\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}0-9]+/simu";
preg_match($regex, $string, $matches);

// Send a UTF-8 header out so it looks nice.
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

// Dump the matches.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

And here are the results of that script:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 摄氏零下253
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some extensions to regular expressions like named characters groups.

You can the following group:

> \p{Han} the chinese Han characters.

The regex is then:

```
[\p{Han}]+[0-9]+
```